# EXTJS Tab Panel Not Rending Tabs

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

I have a new application that was created used the Sencha App create. When I am trying to add a tabpanel. It allows me to add the panel but the tabs are not being displayed as cards. They are being displayed as label's only. I can click on each label and it displays the data in the tabs but I need to have them look like tabs.

Here is the code I am using to create the panel.

```
{xtype: 'panel', itemId:'tpTest', region: 'west', width: 250,title: "insert form goes here",collapsible:true, items:
[
    { xtype: 'tabpanel', layout:'card', activeTab: 0, items:
        [
            { title:'Tab1', html:'Test'},
            { title:'Tab2', html:'Test 1'}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Here is the screen capture of what I am seeing:

[image]

I also get a strange warning stating the following:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

bootstrap,js: 
xhr.open('GET', url, false);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your suffering from overnesting, so a tabpanel contained within another panel.

Instead try this:

```
{ 

    xtype: 'tabpanel', 
    itemId:'tpTest', 
    region: 'west',
    width: 250,
    activeTab: 0, 
    title: 'insert form goes here',
    collapsible: true,
    items:[
        { title:'Tab1', html:'Test'},
        { title:'Tab2', html:'Test 1'}
    ]
}
```

So remove the parent panel item . You also dont need to specify card layout as it already uses this by default for a tab panel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried removing the parent panel and get the same functionality. I inserted your code and there is no change in UI appearance. Here is what I have now:

{ xtype: 'tabpanel', layout:'card', activeTab: 0, region: 'west', width: 250, collapsible:true, items:
 [
  { title:'Tab1', html:'Test'},
  { title:'Tab2', html:'Test 1'}
 ]
}
@mindparse

Comment: what version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Can you post your full code with this tab panel in. I can see you are configured it as west region, so you are obviously using it within a border layout of a parent item. That should help me further understand whats going on here for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by doing a sencha app refresh. Thanks everyone